# Leaflet Javascript: zoom to layer only on load

Tags: leaflet, wfs

I have a WFS layer, updated in a loop, and I want the view to be centered on it only the first time the map is loaded; next, when the user moves  the map or waits 20 secs, there is a movend function that reloads the wfs, but I don't want the view to be recentered again. So I tried a variable, but I'm not successful

```
    function loadGeoJson_cycliste(data) {
            var done;
    if (done === 'OK')
            { featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers();
        featureLayer_cycliste.addData(data); }
            else {
    featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers();
    featureLayer_cycliste.addData(data);
                    map.fitBounds(featureLayer_cycliste.getBounds)
    });
             var done = 'OK';
       


     };
    
function load_wfs_cycliste() {
    if (map.getZoom() > startatzoom_cycliste) {
        var geoJsonUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'getFeature',
            typeName: wfs_cycliste,
            maxFeatures: 100,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            format_options: 'callback: getJson_cycliste',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
        };

          var customParams = {
            bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
        };

        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
 //       console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'getJson_cycliste',
            success: loadGeoJson_cycliste
        });
      
          

    } else {
        featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers();
    }
};
```

**trigger :**

```
function reloadcom() {
if (map.hasLayer(featureLayer_cycliste)) load_wfs_cycliste();

                setTimeout(reloadcom, 20000);
        };

 
featureLayer_cycliste.on('add', function(evt) {
        load_wfs_cycliste();
});

map.on('moveend', reloadcom);

reloadcom();
```

Comment: @TomazicM  I edited with map. fitbounds, featurelayer get bounds, and it was zooming to the extent of the layer but coulnt get out or zoom out

Comment: Just move your `var done;` variable definition outside `loadGeoJson_cycliste` function to make it global variable, so value will persist from call to call.

Comment: @Tomazic Thanks. I solved it through duplicating the functions. I'm sorry I didn't include the load_wfs_cycliste function

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by duplicating the functions. onAdd now call nested "firstload" functions which call the bounds; they would do that only once.

**2nd and next loads :**

```
    function loadGeoJson_cycliste(data) {
     featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers()
        featureLayer_cycliste.addData(data)
};    

function load_wfs_cycliste() {
    if (map.getZoom() > startatzoom_cycliste) {
        var geoJsonUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'getFeature',
            typeName: wfs_cycliste,
            maxFeatures: 100,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            format_options: 'callback: getJson_cycliste',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
        };

          var customParams = {
            bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
        };

        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
 //       console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'getJson_cycliste',
            success: loadGeoJson_cycliste
        });
      
          

    } else {
        featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers();
    }
};
```

**first load :**

```
var tdfbounds;
var mCenterlat;
var mCenterlng;

function loadGeoJson_cycliste_firstload(data) {

         featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers()
         featureLayer_cycliste.addData(data)

    var tdfbounds = featureLayer_cycliste.getBounds();
        var mCenterlat  = tdfbounds.getCenter().lat;
        var mCenterlng  = tdfbounds.getCenter().lng;
        map.setView(new L.LatLng(mCenterlat, mCenterlng), 10);
};


function load_wfs_cycliste_firstload() {
    if (map.getZoom() > startatzoom_cycliste) {
        var geoJsonUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'getFeature',
            typeName: wfs_cycliste,
            maxFeatures: 100,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            format_options: 'callback: getJson_cycliste',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
        };

          var customParams = {
            bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
        };

        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
 //       console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'getJson_cycliste',
            success: loadGeoJson_cycliste_firstload
        });



    } else {
        featureLayer_cycliste.clearLayers();
    }
};
```

**triggers :**

```
function reloadcom() {
if (map.hasLayer(featureLayer_cycliste)) load_wfs_cycliste();

                setTimeout(reloadcom, 20000);
        };

 
featureLayer_cycliste.on('add', function(evt) {
        load_wfs_cycliste_firstload();
});

map.on('moveend', reloadcom);

reloadcom();
```